# Add rows in a data.frame so that each group is of equal length

Tags: r, dplyr, time-series

I have the following data.frame, mimicking a time series analysis:

```
df <- data.frame(country = rep(c("US", "GB", "DK"), each = 18),
             y = runif(54),
             time = c(-8:9, 0:17, -17:0))
```

Meaning, I have 18 years of data, with an event of interest occurring somewhere within those 18 years. The `time` column sets that particular year to zero and counts forward / backward as appropriate.

I need to make every group (US, GB, DK) the same size, set to the maximum that it could be, filling in all the missing data with `NA`. In other words, I'd need the final data.frame to look like this:

```
df2 <- data.frame(country = rep(c("US", "GB", "DK"), each = 18+17),
             y = c(rep(NA, 9), df[df$country == "US",]$y, rep(NA, 8),
                   df[df$country == "GB",]$y, rep(NA, 17),
                   rep(NA, 17), df[df$country == "DK",]$y),
             time = rep(-17:17, times = 3))
```

In the real data, there are 176 countries, each with the intervention occurring in different years. So I really don't want to have to hard-code it like I just did! Is there a way to do this, perhaps with `dplyr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `tidyr::complete` to do this easily.  Since data will be grouped by `country` use `min(df$time)` and `max(df$time)` instead of `min(time)` and `max(time)` in `from` & `to` arguments of `seq`, so that `min` and `max` of `df$time` are used instead of **grouped max & min**.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% group_by(country) %>%
  complete(time = seq(min(df$time), max(df$time), 1))

# A tibble: 105 x 3
# Groups:   country [3]
   country  time       y
   <chr>   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1 DK        -17 0.0796 
 2 DK        -16 0.361  
 3 DK        -15 0.503  
 4 DK        -14 0.415  
 5 DK        -13 0.426  
 6 DK        -12 0.0370 
 7 DK        -11 0.00867
 8 DK        -10 0.0254 
 9 DK         -9 0.619  
10 DK         -8 0.862  
# ... with 95 more rows
```

see last 12 rows of above result

```
df %>% group_by(country) %>%
  complete(time = seq(min(df$time), max(df$time), 1)) %>%
  ungroup() %>% tail(12)

# A tibble: 12 x 3
   country  time      y
   <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl>
 1 US          6  0.957
 2 US          7  0.265
 3 US          8  0.216
 4 US          9  0.445
 5 US         10 NA    
 6 US         11 NA    
 7 US         12 NA    
 8 US         13 NA    
 9 US         14 NA    
10 US         15 NA    
11 US         16 NA    
12 US         17 NA
```

---

Once aware how `complete` works, the above work can be done in a single line of code as-

```
complete(df, time, nesting(country))
# A tibble: 105 x 3
    time country       y
   <int> <chr>     <dbl>
 1   -17 DK       0.0796
 2   -17 GB      NA     
 3   -17 US      NA     
 4   -16 DK       0.361 
 5   -16 GB      NA     
 6   -16 US      NA     
 7   -15 DK       0.503 
 8   -15 GB      NA     
 9   -15 US      NA     
10   -14 DK       0.415 
# ... with 95 more rows
```

Comment: `dplyr` and StackOverflow never cease to amaze. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to have been of help.  See edit also.